# Youtube and Facebook videos do not play on Chrome, videos loading forever

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

Yesterday I got this weird issue where videos on youtube and some on facebook would keep on loading forever

[image]

My internet connection is on, and videos play on IE and Edge

I have also tried reinstalling Chrome but it didn't help..

**Is there anyone who is experiencing something simmiral? Why Youtube does not play with chrome?**

**EDIT:** I have found solution but it's not very nice, so if anyone knows how to make it work with skipping the adds please post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have managed to get something, I have wiped bookmarks and history and disabled everything and videos started to play again... this gave me an idea...

I started enabling all the extensions one by one and I got a hit (on my first try, lol)...

Apparently it was Adblocker, disabling it makes videos work on both Youtube and Facebook.

If this is happening to you go to chrome and instead of url type in `chrome://extensions/` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> this should open extensions window on chrome.

Then untick the box on `Enabled` or delete the extension completely..

[image]

This is not he best solution as I would like to skip adds and to see videos.

Comment: Rather than disable Adblock entirely it should have an option to disable it for the particular site.  Check the icon it adds to the address bar for the option. That will at least allow you to use Adblock in general but be a bit more selective about sites that do not allow you to skip advertisements.  That said, those advertisements pay for the content you want to watch and without them then you wouldn't have the content. I don't like ads either, but the alternative is subscribing and paying for every site you like individually.

Comment: how come it works under other OSes?  I never realized YouTube had ads, AdBlocker apparently was that good.